# Android : Displaying names of files in asset Folder of app in listview

Tags: android

I tried to display list of files in asset folder but it is not displaying and on debugging i found adapter is null and launches a blank activity . Why is it so having no idea and unable to find if any mistake I have done. I am new to this field any information will be appreciated

```
public class JobListActivity extends Activity {

private ListView m_JobListView;
private String[] m_Filename;
private String m_Path;
private ArrayList<String> m_JobList;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    m_JobListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.joblistView1);
    m_Path = "file:///android_asset/";

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    m_JobList = new ArrayList<String>();
    m_JobListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.joblistView1);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(JobListActivity.this,
            R.layout.activity_joblist, android.R.id.text1, m_JobList);
    try {
        m_Filename = getAssets().list("file:///android_asset/");

        if (m_Filename != null && (null != m_JobList)) {

            for (int i = 0; i < m_Filename.length; i++) {
                m_JobList.add(m_Filename[i]);
            }

            if ((m_Filename.length == 0) || (null == m_Filename)) {
                m_JobList.add(0, "No sheets available");
            }
        }



        if (adapter != null) {
            if (m_JobListView != null) {
                if (m_JobList != null) {
                    m_JobListView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You're saying at this line - if (adapter != null) { - adapter is null?  I don't see how that's possible since the new operator should either return an instance or throw an exception.

Comment: nasch : You were correct, it wasn't null, m_JobList was null, now it is rectified since I got the issue

Answer (score 1):

> m_Filename = getAssets().list("file:///android_asset/");

replace this line by following line will work

> m_Filename = getAssets().list("");

Comment: Add this line to... what? Please [edit] your answer so it's clear what you're suggesting.